# Can I avoid using letters to denote partial derivatives of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $F$ is a two variable function, defined by $F(x,y)=x^2+y$. We can then calculate the partials of $F$ as $F_x(x,y)=2x$ and $F_y(x,y)=1$. Then it is clear that $F_x(1,0)=2$ and $F_y(0,1)=1$. That is to say that we can find expression for the partials of a function and then evaluate its values at different points by a simple substitution.

If one wishes to find the derivative of $u^2+v$ with respect to $u$, it wouldn't make much sense to define an entirely new function involving $u$ and $v$ when we have a function whose expression at $x=u$ and $y=v$ looks exactly the same. So the derivative is $F_x(u,v)=2u$. So far I don't have any complaints.

But what if instead we had the expression $y^2+x$? We should follow the same procedure and arrive at the correct result; but it just feels wrong to treat $x$ and $y$ as independent variables used to define a function at first, and then as merely a point at which we are evaluating a function (which is again given in terms of the independent variables $x$ and $y$).

I feel that something like a list of independent variables used to define a function should have no form (such as denoting them by $x,y,z,$ etc). We need only know their expressions at an arbitrary point, say $(x,y)$.

I also think that a function shouldn't exclusively be of some variables $x,y,z$ when there is no context. When "distance" is defined we may talk about velocity as a function of "distance". But when we want to define a function of arbitrary variables, why give them names? Why not say that $G$ is a 3 variable function and $G(x,y,z)=xy+z$? Also, this would mean that we shouldn't use letters to indicate the variables with respect to which partial derivatives have been taken. Any thoughts will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've seen notation like $F_2$ to denote the partial derivative of $F$ wrt its second argument.

Comment: I don't entirely follow. Two questions to start: (1) What do you mean by "the derivative of $u^2 + v$"? You say you want to avoid defining an entirely new function, but isn't $u^2 + v$ an entirely new function (of $u$ and $v$)? (2) What do you mean by "the expression $y^2+x$"? Do you mean the _function_? You can't take a derivative of an "expression"...

Comment: @Y.Forman our books often write "let $f$ be a function of $x$ and $y$." What I meant is that functions shouldn't depend on what letters we have used to describe them and that whether it's $x,y$ or $u,v$ there is only one function here, just evaluated at different points.

Comment: $F(x,y)=x^2+y$ and $F(u,v)=u^2+v$

Comment: @HritRoy That's true. But you do need a way of referring to the different arguments. You can use a system like spaceisdarkgreen suggested, where you number the arguments -- sometimes that is clearer -- or you can give each argument an arbitrary name and refer to them that way. This is often convenient even before derivatives are introduced: describing the function $F(x,y) = x^2+y$ without using the letters is  cumbersome.

Comment: @HritRoy Are those two $F$s the same function, or different functions?

Comment: @Y.Forman OP is searching for a way to take the partial derivative that wont require him to know the names of the input

Comment: @Holo But the example OP gives for something OP would like -- $G(x,y,z) = xy+z$ -- already uses names for input.

Comment: @Y.Forman Same. Evaluated at $(x,y)$ and then $(u,v)$.

Comment: @HritRoy If $(x,y)$ are the variables you used to _define_ the function, then I wouldn't _evaluate_ the function at a different set of variables also called $(x,y)$. That could lead to confusion.

Comment: @Y.Forman no you misunderstood me. I want to avoid calling $F$ a function of $x,y,z$. I wrote that to provide an expression for $F$ at an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Y.Forman exactly. And to avoid this possibility of confusion altogether, I want to avoid calling $F$ a function of anyone. Simply a function of 2 variables whose value at $(x,y)$ is $x^2+y$ or whatever

Comment: @HritRoy You can do that: you can say $F$ is a function of two argument whose result is given by squaring the first argument and adding the result ot the second argument. But, as I said, this is more cumbersome than writing $F(x,y) = x^2 + y$.

Comment: @HritRoy Similar confusion will result if you reuse the symbol $F$ as a variable to represent a number. What's the value of the function $F$ at the point $(F,F^2)$? Reusing symbols breeds confusion.

Comment: @Y.Forman and that is the very reason I want to make sure that $(x,y)$ can have only one meaning when I'm doing a problem. I will indeed write $F(x,y)=x^2+y$ but that doesn't mean I'm saying that $F$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. I'm saying that $F$ takes the arguments $(x,y)$ and maps it to $x^2+y$

Comment: @HritRoy So, if I understand you correctly, you're okay naming the function $F$ (and you'll avoid reusing that symbol), but you're not okay naming its arguments (and avoiding reusing those symbols)?

Comment: @Y.Forman Yes and there is a reason for that too. I understand your point clearly. I am sure that I won't denote a real number by $F$; however I may want to evaluate $F$ at $(x,y)$ and then at $(2x,2y)$ in certain situations. As I said, I don't have a problem in general, but in some cases I do.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you! This will make my problem much easier.

Comment: @HritRoy Okay. In that case, if it's a function of finite arguments, the notation system spaceisdarkgreen suggested might work for you. If it's a function of infinite arguments, I'm not sure if there's a good way to refer to one particular argument without naming it. You could also choose other symbols you'd never use for a real number -- like, say $F$ is a function of square and triangle.

Comment: For a univariate function $F$, I think $F^{(n)}$ is fairly standard notation for its $n$th derivative. So for a function in two variables $F^{(n_1,n_2)}$ seems natural for the $n_1$th derivative in its first variable and $n_2$ in its second.

Comment: @Y.Forman Haha. Yes that would work for me too. However on a different note, shouldn't functions work as just a map? Regardless of what I call it a function of? Calling F a function of this or that is fine but what it really does is takes a value and returns a value to us? So maybe it doesn't really matter (except for convenience perhaps) what we call it a function of?

Comment: @Doris That's nice too!

Comment: @HritRoy Yes, that seems right -- the names are just for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

You are absolutely right: it is useful to be able to denote the partial derivatives of a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ without having to name its arguments, just as it is useful to be able to denote the derivative of a one-variable function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as $g':\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. After all, $g'(0)$ is neither $\mathrm dg(0)/\mathrm d0$ nor $\mathrm dg(0)/\mathrm dx$.

Spivak in [*Calculus on Manifolds*](https://archive.org/details/SpivakM.CalculusOnManifolds) denotes the partial derivatives of $f$ as $D_1f,D_2f,\dots,D_nf$, and higher-order derivatives as $D_{1,1}f$ and so on. On pages 44-45 he discusses the drawbacks of the classical $\partial f/\partial x$ notation.

Answer (score 2):

the whole problem of naming is something we can't completely erase. but we can avoid it using conventions:

instead of $F_x(u,v)=2u$ we will say $F_u(u,v)=2u$.

for points we will use $x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and $y_0,y_1,\cdots,y_n$

and such.

conventions really are just a temporary solution until one start to understand from how the it was written because they are not the same everywhere.

for example i saw times where a function with $2$ variables look like this: $F(x_0,x_1)$, i.e. $x_0,x_1$ are the variables, and saw other texts writing $\text{"at the point $(x_0,y_0)$..."}$, in this paper it is clear that $x_0$ is not a refer to variable.

---

the notation @spaceisdarkgreen suggested is a nice way but this notation can create even more confusion when you work with sequences of functions.

it is a lot more effective to write what you want to do clearly.

---

although that i said that conventions are not always the same some of them are so widely used so even if you don't use the convention you will understand it.

@Doris suggested a nice way

another ways to write it: 
$$\partial_{n_1}^{k_1}\partial_{n_2}^{k_2}\partial_{n_3}^{k_3}\cdots f$$ 
and
$$\frac {\partial ^{k_1+k_2+k_3+\cdots}f}{\partial {n_1}^{k_1}\,\partial {n_2}^{k_2}\,\partial {n_3}^{k_3}\cdots}$$

where $k_i$ the how many derivative we take for the variable $n_i$

other way is:$$D_{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots}f$$
here $a_i$ is really the place of the variable(e.g. $F_x(x,y)=D_1F(x,y)$)

here for higher degree of derivative you repeat the same number: $D_{1,1,2}f$ is the second derivative of the first variable and the first derivative of the second variable.